# How to vertically align content on every page?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I'm using the `memoir` document class.

Is there a way to apply spacing per page so that the content on each page is vertically centered? I'm thinking of something along the lines of `\raggedbottom` or `\flushbottom` not `\vfill` or `\centering`. I want this to be applied to every page using (presumably) one command at the top of the document.

I am currently using `\raggedbottom` because I dislike the spacing between paragraphs from `\flushbottom` (the default?). On some pages the content does not vertically fill the page, say 8 inches of a 12 inch high page, ignoring page margins. In those cases I want there to be 2 inches of padding above the content and 2 inches below the content, not 4 inches below the content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try

```
\raggedbottom
\makeatletter
\let\@texttop\@textbottom
\makeatother
```

Comment: Mostly works, only caveat for me is that it doesn't work with \clearpage. Whenever a \clearpage occurs that page (the one that has been cleared) does not vertically center the content.

Comment: It appears I should be using `\pagebreak` not `\clearpage`. That fixes the issue for me.

Comment: @jdw. Indeed. When LaTeX builds the page, it puts `\@texttop` before the text and `\@textbottom` after the text. `\raggedbottom` defines `\@texttop` as `\relax` and `\@textbottom` as `\vskip 0pt plus .0001fil` which means glue with infinite stretchabiity but of very low order. If you make `\@texttop` equals to `\@textbottom`, you have the same glue with the same stretchability before and after your text, which means centering. `\breakpage`, just cuts the text and everything goes well.

Comment: @jdw. `\clearpage` adds `\vskip 0pt plus 1fil` between your text and `\@textbottom`, which is glue with infinite stretchability of a higher order. This _crushes_ the glue in `\@texttop`. Either don't use `\clearpage` or redefines `\@texttop` and `\@textbottom` as `\vfill`.